# GIt Merge Issue : Changes of my one file is not visible in git merge on the UI

Tags: gitlab, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have 3 branches (Feature branch (a), Feature branch(b)  and develop branch) .
Aim is to merge both feature branches with their latest changes in the develop branch .

Sequence of events :

1. Merged feature branch (a) into develop
2. Merge feature branch (b) into develop
3. Updated a file (xyz) by removing a field and did some other files updation (addition) as well in branch (a)
4. Raised a merge request to merge updated feature branch (a) into develop .

Issue :

- Changes of file (xyz) is not visible in the changes tab on the git UI
- It not even visible while merging conflicts from the UI

Comment: You've added both the GitHub and GitLab tags. Can you specify which you're having a problem with?

Comment: It's for gitlab only .